# FormBuilder's "In Groups" field does not support permissions

Tags: groups, formbuilder

When using the field "In Groups" in FormBuilder it does not limit the groups to the ones I have ACL permissions to but lists them all. Other groups selections in CiviCRM do this. Is this by intention or wrong behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue, being tracked here:

https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4513